# Search a particular string with grep

Tags: command-line, grep

I want to search in a file with a particular string and show only those lines that exactly match with the string but that doesn't seem to work with `grep -w`.

This is just an example as I would be searching for a string in a script and then want to display only those line that exactly matches, not "string-xxxx" or "string.io".

Does anyone have any idea?

```
root@ubuntu-client:/var/lib/apt/lists# cat aa
aide is good
this is aide one
that is aide-common good
aide-good is not ok
hello aide-help
root@ubuntu-client:/var/lib/apt/lists# 

oot@ubuntu-client:/var/lib/apt/lists# grep -w aide aa
aide is good
this is aide one
that is aide-common good
aide-good is not ok
hello aide-help
root@ubuntu-client
```

Comment: "Exact" matching has a specific meaning in grep - the _entire line_ should match the pattern. Is that actually what you want? If not, for the example input you have given, show us the output you are expecting to see

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42454344/10477326

Answer (score 5):

The issue you are bumping up against is that `-` is considered as a non-word character, so that the string `aide` in `aide-` is considered a word. From `man grep`:

> ```
>   -w, --word-regexp
>           Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole
>           words.  The test is that the matching substring must  either  be
>           at  the  beginning  of  the  line,  or  preceded  by  a non-word
>           constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the  end
>           of  the  line  or  followed by a non-word constituent character.
>           Word-constituent  characters  are  letters,  digits,   and   the
>           underscore.  This option has no effect if -x is also specified.
> ```

It is not clear what your actual requirements are however if you want to match a string that is not preceded or followed by any *non-whitespace* character instead, you could switch to grep's PCRE mode and do something like

```
$ cat aa
aide is good
this is aide one
that is aide-common good
aide-good is not ok
hello aide-help

$ grep -P '(?<!\S)aide(?!\S)' aa
aide is good
this is aide one
```

Note however that this will necessarily also exclude other trailing punctuation like `aide,` and `aide.`. To match `aide` only where it is not preceded or followed by a *word character or hyphen*, you could use

```
grep -P '(?<!(\w|-))aide(?!(\w|-))' aa
```

For reference, see [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: @sunny_hkhk To include punctuation the lookarounds can be expanded to e.g. `grep -P '(?<=\s|^)aide(?=\s|$|, |\. )'`.